# R : How to tag a subject if one of their columns has a certain value

Tags: r, dplyr

This is what my data looks like:

```
+---------+--+----------+--+
| Subj_ID |  | Location |  |
+---------+--+----------+--+
|       1 |  |        1 |  |
|       1 |  |        2 |  |
|       1 |  |        3 |  |
|       2 |  |        1 |  |
|       2 |  |        4 |  |
|       2 |  |        2 |  |
|       3 |  |        1 |  |
|       3 |  |        2 |  |
|       3 |  |        5 |  |
+---------+--+----------+--+
```

In this dataset, only subject 1 has a location value of 3, so I want to label subject 1 as YES for intervention. Since subject 2 and 3 didn't have a location value of 3, they need to be labeled as false.

This is what I want the data to look like.

```
| Subj_ID |  | Location | Intervention |
+---------+--+----------+--------------+
|       1 |  |        1 | YES |
|       1 |  |        2 | YES |
|       1 |  |        3 | YES |
|       2 |  |        1 | NO  |
|       2 |  |        4 | NO  |
|       2 |  |        3 | NO  |
|       3 |  |        1 | NO  |
|       3 |  |        2 | NO  |
|       3 |  |        5 | NO  |
+---------+--+----------+-----+
```

Thanks in advance for the help! Dplyr preferred if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `dplyr` is after grouping by 'Subj_ID', check whether 3 is `%in/%` Location which returns a single TRUE/FALSE, change that to a numeric index to replace the values with "NO", "YES"

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Subj_ID) %>%
   mutate(Intervention =  c("NO", "YES")[(3 %in% Location)+1])
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   Subj_ID [3]
#  Subj_ID Location Intervention
#    <int>    <dbl> <chr>       
#1       1        1 YES         
#2       1        2 YES         
#3       1        3 YES         
#4       2        1 NO          
#5       2        4 NO          
#6       2        2 NO          
#7       3        1 NO          
#8       3        2 NO          
#9       3        5 NO
```

---

Or use `any`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Subj_ID) %>%
   mutate(Intervention = case_when(any(Location == 3) ~ "YES", TRUE ~ "NO"))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$Intervention <- with(df1, c("NO", "YES")[1 + (Subj_ID %in% 
             Subj_ID[Location == 3])])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Subj_ID = rep(1:3, each = 3),
             Location = c(1:3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5))
```

Comment: I needed to expand the code to match for more than 1 location value and ended up removing the 'any' to have it work.

`mutate(Intervention = case_when(Location == 3 | Location == 5 ~ "YES", TRUE ~ "NO"))`
I then realized that this also works: `mutate(PWI = case_when(any(location_la == 7) | any(location_la == 8) ~ "YES", TRUE ~ "NO"))` So now I'm wondering what's the point of `any`?

I also notice that you and the other commenter have this +1 thing happening, what's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match` for each `Subj_ID` to check if 3 is present in any `Location`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Subj_ID) %>%
  mutate(Intervention = c('Yes', 'No')[is.na(match(3,Location)) + 1])
  #Can also use
  #mutate(Intervention = c('No', 'Yes')[(match(3,Location, nomatch = 0L) > 0) + 1])

#  Subj_ID Location Intervention
#    <int>    <dbl> <chr>       
#1       1        1 Yes         
#2       1        2 Yes         
#3       1        3 Yes         
#4       2        1 No          
#5       2        4 No          
#6       2        2 No          
#7       3        1 No          
#8       3        2 No          
#9       3        5 No
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Subj_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
Location = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: How would you modify this to match more than 1 location value? I tried 
`[(match(3 | 5,Location, nomatch = 0L) > 0) + 1])` but that failed

Comment: @myfatson Use `mutate(Intervention = c('Yes', 'No')[all(is.na(match(c(3, 5),Location))) + 1])` in the last line.