# "Result must have length..." error with 'complete.cases'

Tags: r

This is an extension of the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59571012/r-how-to-tag-a-subject-if-one-of-their-columns-has-a-certain-value/59571605?noredirect=1#comment105341650_59571605) where I was looking for a way to automate my labeling of subjects into groups based on if their data matched my filter.

Prior to attempting to the automating labeling, this is what I had.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Subj_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                 Location = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5)), class = "data.frame", 
            row.names = c(NA, -9L))


df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(group=
       if_else(Subj_ID ==1,
               "Treatment",
       if_else(Subj_ID == 2,
                "Control","Withdrawn")))


complete.df <- df2 %>% filter(complete.cases(.))
```

In my actual data, there are some rows that have NA's and I need to be able to filter for both complete and incomplete cases so I can review the sub-data sets separately if needed. 
My new code looks like this which assigns a subject to a group based on if they have a location data point 4 or 5:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(group=
       if_else(Subj_ID ==1,
               "Treatment",
       if_else(Subj_ID == 2,
                "Control","Withdrawn")))

df3 <- df2 %>% ##this chunk breaks filter(complete.cases(.))
  group_by(Subj_ID) %>%
  mutate(group2 = case_when(any(Location == 4) | any(Location == 5) ~ "YES", TRUE ~ "NO"))

complete.df <- df3 %>% filter(complete.cases(.))
```

Once I generate df3 by mutating df2, my filter(complete.cases(.)) subsequently fails.

Yet, if I were to generate df3 by manual recoding, it works! As so:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(group=
       if_else(Subj_ID ==1,
               "Treatment",
       if_else(Subj_ID == 2,
                "Control","Withdrawn")))

df3 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(group2=
       if_else(Subj_ID ==2 | 
              Subj_ID ==3,
               "TRUE", "FALSE"))

complete.df <- df3 %>% filter(complete.cases(.))
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be the `group_by` attribute which causes the issue and can be solved by `ungroup`ing and then apply the `filter`.  In the OP's last code block (manual coding), it is not creating a grouping attribute and thus it works

```
library(dplyr)
df3 %>%
       ungroup %>%
       filter(complete.cases(.))
```

Or instead of `complete.cases` in `filter`, we can use `!is.na` with `filter_all` without removing the grouping attribute

```
df3 %>% 
    filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

---

OP mentioned about the last code block is working, but it doesn't have any group attribute.  If we create one, then it fails too

```
df3 %>% 
     group_by(group) %>%
     filter(complete.cases(.))
```

> Error: Result must have length 3, not 9

Comment: I spent maybe 5 hours fighting with this, you answered correctly within 5 minutes of my post. Thank you so much!